# TELEGRAM BOT - Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Im trying to create a telegram bot that forwards messages that are sent to the bot to my channel, allowing users to send messages anonymously to the channel.
This is my script and im having this issue, how do i fix it? :

```
Exception has occurred:
TypeError Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 
'update_queue'   
File "C:\Users\nrsak\Documents\TelegramBot.py", line 18, in main
     updater = Updater(bot=bot)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nrsak\Documents\TelegramBot.py", line 31, in <module>     
     main()

TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

This is my script, I have tried downgrading the telegram bot version to "python-telegram-bot==13.13" but it still isn't working :

```
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, filters

# Initialize the bot with your API token
bot = Bot(token="XXXXXXX")

# Define your target channel's chat ID (as an integer)
target_channel_id = XXXXX

# Define a function to forward messages
def forward_message(update, context):
    message = update.message
    # Forward the message to your target channel
    bot.send_message(chat_id=target_channel_id, text=message.text)

def main():
    # Create an Updater without the use_context argument
    updater = Updater(bot=bot)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Set up the message handler to trigger the forward_message function
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & Filters.chat(chat_id=target_channel_id), forward_message))

    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  From https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.updater.html, you're supposed to include a ```update_queue``` parameter as well.

Comment: @ewokx i have now added : 
import queue  
import update_queue

but the error it's giving me now is : File "c:\Users\nrsak\Documents\TelegramBot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import update_queue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'update_queue'

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an update queue. See [the documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater.update_queue). For information on such queues, see the [asyncio-queue documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue).

Updated code:

```py
from asyncio import queue

my_queue = queue.Queue()

# ...

def main():
    updater = Updater(bot=bot, update_queue=my_queue)
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved that issue but now a new one appeared saying :
 File "c:\Users\nrsak\Documents\TelegramBot.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\nrsak\Documents\TelegramBot.py", line 25, in main
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'

Comment: The `Updater` class has no attribute, nor method called `dispatcher` ([see the docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.updater.html#updater)). Also modifying chat data using a dispatcher isn't possible since version `20.0` ([see here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0#applicationdispatcher)).

Comment: i see, so what i can do to fix the issue?

Comment: Use [`Application.add_handler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.add_handler).

Comment: I added it to the script but now i have this new error, I cant seem to find the replacement and fix for it anywhere else :  
File "c:\Users\nrsak\Documents\TelegramBot.py", line 25, in main
    Application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & filters.CHAT(chat_id=target_channel_id), forward_message))
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '_Chat' object is not callable

Comment: Does it work if you try to remove `chat_id`? This should not be the issue though.